# Configure search engine to crawl dynamic content displayed by webparts

Tags: web-part, search

I have a question about searching dynamic content in SharePoint 2010.
I need to configure SharePoint search engine in a web portal based on webparts where the content of the web is dynamic.

An example:
A page (CompanyList.aspx) that includes a webpart that displays a list of companies with basic info. The webpart reads the data info from a sharepoint list.

Each displayed item has a link to another page (eg. CompanyInfo.aspx?companyId=1)
CompanyInfo.aspx has a webpart that displays full information about the company based on companyId.

I want these pages be shown on the search results. How do i set up the search engine to display these dynamic pages?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is create a search rule and configuer a complex URL. To understand what im talking about check this out should help you alot!

Sharepoint 2010 : Configuring Crawls (part 1) - Creating and Managing Content Sources

http://allcomputers.us/windows_server/Sharepoint-2010---Configuring-Crawls-(part-1)---Creating-and-Managing-Content-Sources.aspx

Sharepoint 2010 : Configuring Crawls (part 2) - Creating and Managing Crawl Rules

http://allcomputers.us/windows_server/sharepoint-2010---configuring-crawls-(part-2)---creating-and-managing-crawl-rules.aspx

Sharepoint 2010 : Configuring Crawls (part 3) - Using Server Name Mappings & Controlling Host Distribution

http://allcomputers.us/windows_server/Sharepoint-2010---Configuring-Crawls-(part-3)---Using-Server-Name-Mappings---Controlling-Host-Distribution.aspx

I hope this directs you into the right direction :)